# Problema com geometry pack e grid (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, software

pra falar a verdade essas duas geometrias são muito complicadas, mas infelizmente eu preciso usar essa 2 nesse projeto. Então vamos lá.

primeiro segue o código:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *

class principal:

    def __init__(self):

        principal = Tk()
        principal.geometry("860x540+75+75")
        principal.overrideredirect(True)

        esquerda = PhotoImage(file="altura.png")
        ladoesquerdo = Label(principal, background="WHITE", image=esquerda)
        ladoesquerdo.esquerda = esquerda
        ladoesquerdo.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

        cima = PhotoImage(file="largura.png")
        partedecima = Label(principal, background="WHITE", image=cima)
        partedecima.cima = cima
        partedecima.pack(side=TOP)

        baixo = PhotoImage(file="largura.png")
        partedebaixo = Label(principal, background="WHITE", image=baixo)
        partedebaixo.baixo = baixo
        partedebaixo.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        direita = PhotoImage(file="altura.png")
        ladodireito = Label(principal, background="WHITE", image=direita)
        ladodireito.direito = direita
        ladodireito.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

    #:::::::::: CADASTRO ::::::::::::
        framedoscadastros = LabelFrame(principal, height=475, width=400, text="::::::::::::::: Cadastrar :::::::::::::::").pack(side=LEFT)

        nome0 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Nome:  ").grid(row=0, column=0)
        nome1 = Entry(framedoscadastros, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1)

        sobre0 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Sobrenome:  ").grid(row=1, column=0)
        sobre1 = Entry(framedoscadastros, width=20).grid(row=1, column=1)

        telefone0 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Telefone:  ").grid(row=2, column=0)
        telefone1 = (framedoscadastros, width).grid(row=2, column=1)

        nserie0 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Nº de Série:  ").grid(row=3, column=0)
        nserie1 = Entry(framedoscadastros, width=20).grid(row=3, column=1)

        problema0 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Problema:  ").grid(row=4, column=0)
        problema1 = Text(framedoscadastros, width=20, height=4).grid(row=4, column=1)

        nome1 = Label(framedoscadastros, text="Nome:  ").grid(row=0, column=0)


    #::::::::::: BUSCAR :::::::::::::
        framedebuscarcadastros = LabelFrame(principal, height=475, width=400, text="::::::::::::::: Buscar Cadastros :::::::::::::::").pack(side=RIGHT)

        principal.mainloop

principal()
```

Meu código está o mais nítido que poderia ser, o problema também está bem nítido, porém não sei como resolver. O erro pertinente é:

tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Cria um Frame em cada bloco de execução

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível utilizar os gerenciadores de layout *grid* e *pack* juntos, na mesma janela *master*.

Uma possibilidade para corrigir é, por exemplo, retirar o comando `pack()` no final da linha, no ponto onde é criado o *frame* `framedoscadastros`:

```
framedoscadastros = LabelFrame(principal, height=475, width=400, text="::::::::::::::: Cadastrar :::::::::::::::")
```

Porém, talvez seja necessário reposicionar todos os demais elementos da janela com o *grid*.

Caso precise de um layout diferente e o problema persista, tente projetar esse layout utilizando apenas um tipo de gerenciador (ou *grid* ou *pack*).

Outros problemas no código, são:

Ao instanciar `telefone1`, faltou o nome da classe `Entry` e o parâmetro `width`:

```
telefone1 = Entry(framedoscadastros, width=20).grid(row=2, column=1)
```

E ao chamar o método `mainloop`, faltou o parênteses:

```
principal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ês a questão documentar o código todo com um gerenciador só. Porque sinceramente o 'grid' é muito chato, porém bastante útil. eu tentei colocar os grid's dentro de um 'Label' só que não deu muito certo.

Comment: Uma outra possibilidade é utilizar o [*place*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). Apesar de algumas pessoas acharem mais complicado que o *grid*, talvez ele possa lhe ajudar nesse caso

Comment: verdade, para mim não tem nenhum problema, mas queria tanto que o grid' ajudasse nesse caso

Comment: o gerenciamento com o `place` não deu certo também.